# Node Unzipper - how to know it's finished

Tags: node.js, unzip, synchronous

I'm trying to use the unzipper node module to extract and process a number of files (exact number is unknown).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to know when all the files are processed.  So far, my code looks like this:

```
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
.pipe(unzipper.Parse())
.on('entry', async (entry) => {
    var fileName = entry.path;
    if (fileName.match(someRegex)) {
        await processEntry(entry);
        console.log("Uploaded");
    } else {
        entry.autodrain();
        console.log("Drained");
    }
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to know that unzipper has gone through all the files (i.e., no more `entry` events are forthcoming) *and* all the `entry` handlers have finished so that I know I've finished processing all the files I care about.

I've tried experimenting with the `close` and `finish` events but when I have, they both trigger before `console.log("Uploaded");` has printed, so that doesn't seem right.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Directly [from the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper#parsepromise-syntax-sugar):

> The parser emits `finish` and `error` events like any other stream. The parser additionally provides a promise wrapper around those two events to allow easy folding into existing Promise-based structures.
>
> Example:
>
> ```js
> fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip')
>   .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
>   .on('entry', entry => entry.autodrain())
>   .promise()
>   .then( () => console.log('done'), e => console.log('error',e));
> ```

Comment: I tried that.  Used with my example above, the `finish` event triggers before `console.log("Uploaded");` has printed.  The same thing happens if I try to use the `.promise().then()` pattern.

It's very possible there's something else wrong with my example and--if tweaked--the `finish` approach would work, but I don't know *what's* wrong.